# ASP.NET MVC how to open a page inside popup with a parameter from its parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, popup

I have a web report project where I list various things from database one thing that I'm having issue with is I put a button next to each row in the list on the page and when I press that button, I want to draw a sql query according to the current code in the related row and show the table of that query in a popup.

I'm still newbie on web I'd be appreciated for any help.

this is my main page

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Aktif Stok Listesi</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Cari Kodu</th>
                                <th>Cari Adı</th>
                                <th>Döviz Türü</th>
                                <th>Borç Toplam</th>
                                <th>Alacak Toplam</th>
                                <th>Bakiye</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var x in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a id="btnShowModal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-default pull-left button button4">Detay</a></td>
                                    <td>@x.CARI_KOD</td>
                                    <td>@x.CARI_ISIM.Replace('Ý', 'İ').Replace('Þ', 'Ş').Replace('Ð', 'Ğ')</td>
                                    <td>@x.DOVIZ_TURU</td>
                                    <td>@x.BORC_TOPLAM.ToString("F")</td>
                                    <td>@x.ALACAK_TOPLAM.ToString("F")</td>
                                    <td>@x.BAKIYE.ToString("F")</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Cari Kodu</th>
                                <th>Cari Adı</th>
                                <th>Döviz Türü</th>
                                <th>@Model.Sum(x => x.BORC_TOPLAM)</th>
                                <th>@Model.Sum(x => x.ALACAK_TOPLAM)</th>
                                <th>@Model.Sum(x => x.BAKIYE)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
```

this is my popup page

```
    <div>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">

                        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
                             data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Cari Hareket Kaydı</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form>
                     

@I want to list the details of the line whose button is pressed on the main page here


                                         </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                                            Kapat
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('show');
            });

            $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my sql code I'm using Dapper

```
        public List<CariHareketKaydi> CariHareketKaydi(string id)
        {
            var CariHareket = con.Query<CariHareketKaydi>($"select" +
                $" CAS.CARI_ISIM," +
                $" CAH.CARI_KOD," +
                $" CAH.BELGE_NO," +
                $" CAH.ACIKLAMA," +
                $" CAH.BORC," +
                $" CAH.ALACAK," +
                $" CASE CAH.DOVIZ_TURU WHEN '0' THEN 'TL' END AS DOVIZ_TURU" +
                $" from TBLCAHAR CAH LEFT JOIN TBLCASABIT CAS ON CAH.CARI_KOD = CAS.CARI_KOD" +
                $" WHERE CAH.CARI_KOD = '{id}'");
            return CariHareket.ToList();
        }
```

I've tried giving href to button and directing it to its view but since it refreshing the page popup goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a controller somewhere in your application, you could add a route that returns the popup html like:

```cs
[HttpGet("GetCariHareketKaydi/{rowId}")]
public IActionResult GetCariHareketKaydi(string rowId)
{
    var popupData = CariHareketKaydi(rowId);

    return View("PopUp", new PopupViewModel(popupData));
}
```

And with your popup html, save this to a PopUp.cshtml file, adding your PopUpViewModel to the top of the html like:

```
@model YourNameSpace.PopUpViewModel
    <div>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">

                        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
                             data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
```

Then create the PopUpViewModel class which should contain properties that you want to include in the PopUp.cshtml.

You should then add a class to your buttons in the main table, then add some JavaScript resembling below to your main page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btn-show-modal-class").click(async function (this) {
                var rowId = this["row-id"] // not sure the syntax is quite right here, but you need a unique table row id.

                const response = await fetch(`/GetCariHareketKaydi/${rowId}`); 
                
                let modalContainer = document.getElementById("loginModal");
                modalContainer.innerHtml = await response.text();               

                $("#loginModal").modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
```